# Creating new method c# methodname<Variable>(Variable)

Tags: c#, methods

I found some method like this `ReadAsAsync<T>(this HttpContent content);` in c# and I don't know what kind of method is that and question popup on my head

> "It is possible to create method like this
>   `'methodName<varible>(variable){}'` and does this method exist somewhere?"

For example:

```
public void methodName<string getText>(string text)
{
    getText = text;
}
```

And when I call the method:

```
string sampleText;
methodName<sampleText>("Hello World");
```

So the value of the `sampleText` will become `"Hello World"`.

I know this kind of method is useless because you can set the value of sampleText like this

```
string sampleText = "";
```

But I Just want to make some experiment, Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I found some method like this `ReadAsAsync<T>(this HttpContent content);` in c# and I don't know what kind of method is that and question popup on my head

That's a **generic method**. You call it by specifying the type you want like this:

```
Foo result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Foo>();
```

You can read more about it on MSDN: [Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/512aeb7t.aspx)

> "It is possible to create method like this 'methodName(variable){}' and does this method exist somewhere?"

No, what you're trying to do is not possible. What goes between the `<...>` is a **type**, not a variable.

Comment: So It's means `method<type>` is only use to determine the type of the method?

Comment: @LeoSarmiento The `type` can be a type of some variable in the method, any argument / return type of the method. Also, it can be used as a type argument of some generic method, called from that method.

Comment: @MadSorcerer Now I know, Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

As Thomas Levesque said, `ReadAsAsync<T>(this HttpContent content)` is a generic method, wich can operate with different types, depending on `T` Type parameter.

> So the value of the sampleText will become "Hello World".

if that is what you are looking for you should use `ref` argument.

```
public void methodName(string text, ref string getText)
{
    getText = text;
}
```

How to use:

```
string sampleText;
methodName("Hello World", ref sampleText);
```

Comment: Cool, I can use `ref` instead of `return` to set the value of variable, Thank you for information.

Comment: @LeoSarmiento Yes you can, but be careful with that. Use `return` when it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking at is a `Generic Method`. They're used to reuse the logic contained in your code base, and what you see in between those angle brackets is what's called a `Type Parameter`.

`Type Parameters` are used to either `return` the specified `Type`, or, to specify the type of a parameter.

For instance, let's say that we want to get the names of the properties on a class called `User`

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUserProperties()
{
    return typeof(User).GetProperties().Select(property => property.Name);
}

public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

The problem with the code above is that we can't reuse it for other types, say that we wanted to also get the properties of a `Type` named `School`, we would be constantly creating new methods to get the properties of any given `Type`

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetSchoolProperties()
{
    return typeof(School).GetProperties().Select(property => property.Name);
}

public class School
{
    public string SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To solve this issue, we use a `Generic Method`, a method that isn't constrained to just one `Type` (although constraints can be applied to Type parameters, they're outside of scope for the minute, just try to wrap your mind around this first)

```
void Main()
{
    User user = new User 
    {
        FirstName = "Aydin",
        LastName = "Aydin",
        UserId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
    };

    School school = new School
    {
        SchoolId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Name = "Aydins school"
    };

    var userProperties = GetProperties(user);
    var schoolProperties = GetProperties(school);

    Console.WriteLine ("Retrieving the properties on the User class");
    foreach (var property in userProperties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("> {0}", property);
    }

    Console.WriteLine ("\nRetrieving the properties on the School class");
    foreach (var property in schoolProperties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine ("> {0}", property);
    }
}   

public static IEnumerable<string> GetProperties<T>(T t)
{
    return t.GetType().GetProperties().Select(property => property.Name);
}

public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class School
{
    public string SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```